# Turn off mod rewrite for specific template in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

If I have a view located at application/views/templates/games/gamename/ is there a way to turn off mod_rewrite for that directory?

Also, is there a way to not use the smarty templating for that view?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a java script game which unfortunately is having trouble getting data from the backend, therefore the game fails to load and gets stuck on the preloader. This is also why I want to turn off the smarty template because it is not properly loading the correct assets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're focusing yourself in the wrong way to solve the problem. If you're having trouble with your request from the frontend to the backend, then, change the call in the JS to point out the right file, or route the call correctly in `application/config/routes.php`